# Reordering the labels in an R graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi Stack Overflow Community! I am attempting to reorder the items in the attached legend to a specific order that I would like to input. The order is: `Distal`, `rTub`, `Mid`, `Prox`.

I have tried the `order` function and `scale_y_discrete()`. `scale_y_discrete()` didn't work because the y axis is graphing a count frequency, and the data is stored as the text seen in the legend. The code I'm using to output the graph is below

```
p <- Scaphoid_dataF %>%
  ggplot( aes(x=Age, fill = FxLoc, order = )) +
  geom_histogram() +
  labs(y = "Count of Fractures", x = "Patient Age", title = "Frequency of Fractures vs Age")
p + theme_bw() + scale_fill_grey()
```

[Graph output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzpcN.png)

[image]

Comment: Set the appropriate factor levels? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph?rq=1. We can't reproduce your plot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Answer (score 3):

Set the factor orders:

```r
Scaphoid_dataF$Age <- factor(Scaphoid_dataF$Age,
                        levels = c("Distal", "rTub", "Mid", "Prox"),
                        ordered = TRUE)
```